# Merge/Remove duplicate MySQL query results

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I'm running a query that retrieves results from multiple tables.

My query retrieves orders from one table called "store_orders_items" and the corresponding customers details from another called "store_orders".

However if there are two orders by one customer the query retrieves the customers details twice as the query selects the orders by the customers id number.

So I get the detail of two orders which is fine but also the customers details twice which I don't want.

How can I adjust my query to retrieve all orders and only on customers details per order?

Here's the query so far:

```
"SELECT   
                                store_orders.order_name, 
                                store_orders.order_address, 
                                store_orders.id, 
                                store_orders.order_town, 
                                store_orders.order_county, 
                                store_orders.order_postcode, 
                                store_orders.order_country, 
                                store_orders.order_email, 
                                store_orders.item_total,                                    
                                product.name, 
                                store_orders_items.sel_item_size, 
                                store_orders_items.sel_item_color,
                                store_orders_items.sel_item_id, 
                                store_orders.order_date, 
                                product.price 
                        FROM 
                                store_orders_items 
                        LEFT JOIN 
                                store_orders 
                        ON 
                                store_orders_items.order_id = store_orders.id 
                        LEFT JOIN 
                                product 
                        ON 
                                store_orders_items.sel_item_id = product.id 
                        WHERE 
                                store_orders_items.order_id=$id "
```

Here's a basic example of what I'm using to output/echo the code:

```
while ($order = mysql_fetch_array($store_orders)){
                $name = $order["name"] ;
                $size = $order["sel_item_size"];
                $color = $order["sel_item_color"];
                $order_name = $order["order_name"];
                $address = $order["order_address"] ;
                $town = $order["order_town"] ;
                $county = $order["order_county"] ;
                $postcode = $order["order_postcode"] ;
                $country = $order["order_country"] ;
                $email = $order["order_email"] ;
                $price = $order["price"];
                $date = $order["order_date"];

                $item = "<li>{$name}</li>" ;
                $item .= "<li>{$color}</li>" ;
                $item .= "<li>{$size}</li>" ;
                $item .= "<li>{$price}</li>" ;
                $item .= "<li>{$date}</li>" ;
                $item .= "<li>{$order_name}</li>" ;
                $item .= "<li>{$address}</li>" ;
                $item .= "<li>{$town}</li>" ;
                $item .= "<li>{$county}</li>" ;
                $item .= "<li>{$postcode}</li>" ;
                $item .= "<li>{$country}</li>" ;
                $item .= "<li>{$email}</li>" ;

                echo $item ;
            }
```

Comment: Why do you need the customer details just once? Just read them from the first row, and ignore them in the subsequent ones.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is not possible. The SQL JOIN operation joins the rows of two tables together based on some criteria, in your case the order_id. The resulting row will contain the data of the attributes you specify in the first part of the SELECT statement.

The real question is what the problem is with retrieving this data twice. You don't *have* to use all the data you retrieve. You can ignore it if you already processed the data of a customer.

Another option, which I do not recommend, is to retrieve all customer data with one query, and then retrieve the order items with other queries.

**EDIT:**
This code should work, based on the code example you provided:

```
// Output order details
$order = mysql_fetch_array($store_orders);

$order_name = $order["order_name"];
$address = $order["order_address"] ;
$town = $order["order_town"] ;
$county = $order["order_county"] ;
$postcode = $order["order_postcode"] ;
$country = $order["order_country"] ;
$email = $order["order_email"] ;
$price = $order["price"];
$date = $order["order_date"];

$orderList = "<ul>";
$orderList .= "<li>{$price}</li>" ;
$orderList .= "<li>{$date}</li>" ;
$orderList .= "<li>{$order_name}</li>" ;
$orderList .= "<li>{$address}</li>" ;
$orderList .= "<li>{$town}</li>" ;
$orderList .= "<li>{$county}</li>" ;
$orderList .= "<li>{$postcode}</li>" ;
$orderList .= "<li>{$country}</li>" ;
$orderList .= "<li>{$email}</li>" ;
$orderList .= "</ul>";

echo $orderList;

// Reset result pointer
mysql_data_seek($store_orders, 0);

// Output Items
echo "<ul>";
while ($order = mysql_fetch_array($store_orders)){
    $name = $order["name"] ;
    $size = $order["sel_item_size"];
    $color = $order["sel_item_color"];

    $item = "<li>{$name}</li>" ;
    $item .= "<li>{$color}</li>" ;
    $item .= "<li>{$size}</li>" ;


    echo $item ;
}
echo "</ul>";
```

The first part of this code retrieves the first row of the mysql result set. From this row the customer data is shown in an html unordered list. Then the code resets the mysql result set by calling the mysql_data_seek() function. Then it loops over all rows in the result set, and outputs all items in another html unordered list. 
You should probably think of another way to display the results, but that change is trivial.

Futhermore, this code assumes that there is at least one row in the $store_orders variable. If this is not always the case, you should check that with the mysql_num_rows() function before executing this code.

Comment: Hey, thanks the reply. It seems your suggestion will work for now. Is memory usage the reason why you wouldn't recommend this solution? I'm having trouble thinking of an alternative at the moment! How else would you go about achieving this?

Comment: If you have a lot of customers you have to execute a lot of queries, which is bad for performance. But can you explain why it is a problem that each order item row in the result also contains the customer data?

Comment: I've made a page that displays all the details of an order i.e. order item(s) and customer details. The problem arises when I want to echo the retrieved information for the order. So if one customer has ordered two items the two items will be displayed but the customers details will also be displayed twice

Comment: Could you show the part of your code where you echo/output the data? That will probably make it easier to give the correct answer.

Comment: @user999267 Show the code in your original question, you can edit it.

Answer (score 0):

you should use group by like this: `group by customer_id`